# Friedman's proof of covering lemma for $L$

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, lo.logic, inner-model-theory

There is a two-page proof of the covering lemma for $L$ using $\Sigma_n$ substructures (Theorem 3.10) in Sy Friedman's *Fine Structure and Class Forcing*, compared to the proof that spans about twenty pages in Devlin. I wonder how "honest" this proof is, namely whether it omits tons of technical details, because the set-up is similar to Devlin's proof (at least superficially; they both use direct systems) but it's suspiciously short. A related question is whether a more detailed proof using this approach can be found somewhere.